# Rails with Redcarpet can't render tables and link no target

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to render a table with Redcarpet in Rails project.

```
module ApplicationHelper

  # for markdown
  class CodeRayify < Redcarpet::Render::HTML
    def block_code(code, language)
      CodeRay.scan(code, language).div
    end
  end

  def markdown(text)
    render_options = {
      filter_html: true,
      hard_wrap: true,
      with_toc_data: true,
      # tables: true,
      link_attributes: { rel: 'nofollow', target: '_blank' }
    }
    coderayified = CodeRayify.new( render_options )

    options = {
        :fenced_code_blocks => true,
        :no_intra_emphasis => true,
        :autolink => true,
        :tables => true,
        :strikethrough => true,
        :lax_html_blocks => true,
        :superscript => true
    }
    markdown_to_html = Redcarpet::Markdown.new(coderayified, options)
    markdown_to_html.render(text).html_safe
  end
  # end: markdown
end
```

Here is the markdown table content:

```
| head | head | head |
|------|------|------|
| content | 1 | 2 |
```

Now I have two question:

1. Can't render tables?
2. The  doesn't with the `target="_blank"` ?

Any idea, please.

Comment: Does uncommenting `# tables: true` fix your table problem?

Comment: @MarkMerritt There are no lucky.